# C# : Execute a Oracle procedure with IN and OUT arguments and throwback the OUT arguments

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I want to execute a stored procedure, here is it :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(var1 IN VARCHAR2, var2 IN VARCHAR2, return_code OUT VARCHAR2, return_code2 OUT VARCHAR2) 
AS BEGIN

DECLARE newId number;
begin
SELECT (NVL(MAX(ID),0) + 1) into newId from CC_INT_CODA;
INSERT INTO CC_INT_CODA
   VALUES (newId, sysdate, 'BEL', '3' , var1, var2, 'AZ', 'TR', 'FG', 'QW', 'XC', 'IO', '1', '0', sysdate, 'TT', 'BB', 'OO', '8', '9', sysdate, '5', '6');
end;

return_code := 'Returntest1';
return_code2 := 'Returntest2';
END TESTPROC;
```

What I want to do in C# is execute this procedure with my IN params and get back the two OUT params in strings.

I can run it only with IN arguments but impossible to get the 2 OUT arguments.

I'm a beginner in Oracle and C# so please be gentle. And sorry for my english.

PS : I'm using the obsolete System.Data.OracleClient.dll assembly, not the standalone Oracle one.

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION :**

Thank you to everyone for your commentrs and answer, finally It worked like it (see below).

```
    Results = "";

    OracleCommand oCommand = new OracleCommand();
    oCommand.Connection = oraConnection;
    oCommand.CommandText = SQL;
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    OracleParameter return_param = oCommand.CreateParameter();
    return_param.ParameterName = "return_code";
    return_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    return_param.DbType = DbType.String;
    return_param.Size = 30;
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(return_param);
    oCommand.ExecuteReader();

    Results = return_param.Value.ToString();    
    oraConnection.Close();
```

Comment: You'll find many similar questions in SO, that show how to call Oracle and how to use out parameters. Did you try something? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Other than setting the `Direction` of the parameters to `Output`, there's not much to it. If you have client code that doesn't work, show it.

Comment: Are you using Parameters in the c# code?

Comment: The problem was that all topics here are done by using the Oracle's ODAC and I don't have this and can't install on the machine for some reasons

Comment: The syntax for `System.Data.OracleClient` and `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` is very similar. In your case there should be no difference at all.

Comment: The `CreateParameter` it's not build the same way. The littles differences made me stuck on it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with dapper:

```
DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add(name: "out_variable", dbType: DbType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
...
database.Execute(query, param);
var outVariable = param.Get<Decimal>("out_variable");
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but unfortunately I'm not using dapper. In fact it's in a "code object" of Blue Prism. But still useful answer, thanks

Comment: @elpocoloco It's practically the same.